# Multiple ajax request state?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing a script that need that executes some paralleled ajax requests. I'm using an ajax array but i want to execute some code(make some tags visible) when all the requests are complete. here's the code hope u can help me.

```
function Update_All(){

    var loading = document.getElementById("loading_image");
    var actualizacion_completa = document.getElementById("actualizacion_completa");
    loading.style.display = "";
    actualizacion_completa.style.display = "none";
    var i=1;
    var ajax= new Array(20);//objetoAjax();
    var limit = 1;
    var ready = 1;
    for (i=1;i<=20;i++)
    {
        var index = i-1;
        ajax[index] = objetoAjax();

        var voatencion = document.getElementById("idatencionf"+i);
        var vohoras = document.getElementById("vhorasf"+i);
        var vtarifa = document.getElementById("tarifaclientef"+i);
        var voexonerado = document.getElementById("vexoneradof"+i);
        var voaprobado = document.getElementById("vaprobadof"+i);
        var campo = document.getElementById("f"+i+"c1");

        if(typeof(campo) != 'undefined' && campo != null){
            var valor = 1;
            if(campo.innerHTML=="Si") valor = 2;
                ajax[index].open("GET","update.php?atencion="+voatencion+"&opc="+5+"&valor="+valor+"&exonerado="+voexonerado.value+"&tarifa="+vtarifa.value+"&horas="+vohoras.value);
            ajax[index].send(null);
            limit = i;
            ajax[index].onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (ajax[index].readyState==4 && ajax[index].status == 200) {
                    ready++;

                    if(ready == limit){
                        loading.style.display = "none";
                        actualizacion_completa.style.display = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            break;
        }       
    }
}
```

the problem is ready never gets equal to limit.

PS: srry about the spanish variable's names;

Comment: this question gets asked all the time.  see http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/

Comment: You're not using jquery, but if you were, this could probably help: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

Comment: srry im new to javascript/ajax and right now im not using jquery. Can you help me with some code though.

Comment: What is `objetoAjax()` in line `ajax[index] = objetoAjax();`?

Comment: what are the contents of `ready` and `limit` after all requests have finished?

Comment: @ZenMaster objetoAjax() is a function that returns a XMLHttpRequest or an ActiveXObject depending on the browser.

Comment: @Michael Sandino limit is 20 and ready is like 7 sometimes 9 others 10.

Answer (score 0):

You already know the limit is 20, no need to augment it every time with this `limit = i;`.

Just set

```
var limit = 20;
```

At the beginning of your script.

It may be that you actually need to set one value less for the limit (19 in this case) due to the array starting with 0.

Also, add this line every time you complete an AJAX request:

```
console.log('ready = ' + ready);
```

This way you can actually see at which value ready is stopping, or if it's not augmenting at all.

Comment: thank you for the console.log(). didnt know about that as i said im just starting with this. so the results are very inconsistent as sometimes ready get to 23 O_O and others it just get to 2. also the var limit = 1 is because sometimes campo is null and when that happens its time to stop.

Answer (score 0):

the value of index inside your onreadystatechange function will not be what you expect.

Suggest replacing the current onreadystatechange with:

```
(function(ajaxItem, ready) {
    ajaxItem.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (ajaxItem.readyState==4 && ajaxItem.status == 200) {
        ready++;

        if(ready == limit){
            loading.style.display = "none";
            actualizacion_completa.style.display = "";
        }
    }
})(ajax[index], ready);
```